# Распарсить время

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть подобные строки в тексте:

```
Sometext: value
Sometext: value,
Time:19:35
Sometext, sometext,
```

Нужно получить строковое значение `value` и `19:35`. В случае с   `str.split(":")`  получаю только `19` . Пробовал писать `str.split("^(.*):(.*)&")`  -не выходит. Подскажите пожалуйста правильный регексп.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/thumb/e/ee/RegExp_tutorial.png/800px-RegExp_tutorial.png

Comment: В последней строке примера у вас после Sometext вообще запятая, какой тут может быть split. И еще, в разных языках регулярные выражения могут по разному обрабатываться, какой язык в вашем случае?

Comment: В моем случе Java. Предположим, что мы не будем учитывать текст "через запятую" (т.е. предположим что его вовсе нету).

Comment: В принципе, если у Вас формат совпадает с 1ой и 2ой строкой, то вы могли бы использовать разделение по : и пробелу. То есть трока 

    Time:19:35 
    //должна выглядеть так
    Time: 19:35
    //тогда сплит вы делаете следующим образом
    str.split(": ");

Comment: @korytoff, с какого бодуна вы поставили сюда метку `java`?

Comment: @Visman странно, не помню что бы я это правил, надо откатить правки

Answer (score 1):

Для выделения значений и времени после двоеточий из этого примера:

```
Sometext: value
Sometext: value,
Time:19:35
Sometext, sometext,
```

можно воспользоваться таким регулярным выражением

```
/:\s*([^,\n\r\t]+)/g
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример https://regex101.com/r/kP2lE4/1

P.S. Если `value` не содержат пробелов, то `[^,\n\r\t]` можно заменить на `[^,\n\r\t\s]`.

Comment: `Нужно получить строковое значение value и 19:35.` <- вот что нужно вопрошающему, а не `Распарсить время`. **P.S.** Это уточнение для тех, кто вопрос не читает!

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Sometext: value
Sometext: value,
Time:19:35
Sometext, sometext,";

preg_match('|Time:(\d{2}):(\d{2})\r|is', $str, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

В ответе :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Time:19:35"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "19" //Часов
  [2]=>
  string(2) "35" //Минут
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для получения всех строк с временем регулярка должна выглядеть так:

```
/(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})/gm
```

Флаг `g` означает глобальный поиск, то есть находит все совпадения.
Флаг `m` означает многострочный текст